# How do I access data from a docked form?

Tags: c#, docking

I'm using http://sourceforge.net/projects/dockpanelsuite/ as a docking control in my application and I have added a form as a docking container, and from it I need to access a string from the main form. I was just messing around to see if I could load it using (Owner as MainWindow), but it did not work.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < (Owner as MainWindow).str.Count; i++)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("A");
        }
```

I always get an error on the first line "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." Is there any way I can access the string str (it is a public string btw) from the docked form?

If it's unclear please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass a ref of the MainForm when you create this form (your docking container).
e.g.

add a constructor in your docking container:

```
MainForm GUImainform;
public dockingContainerForm(ref MainForm mymainform)
{
   GUImainform=mymainform;
}
```

so you can pass MainForm ref to this form when its created:

```
dockingContainerForm dcForm=new dockingContainerForm (ref this);
```

and access your MainForm inside this docking form with `GUImainform`.